# Sprite images keep overlapping after one gets spliced in Space Invaders game

Tags: javascript, arrays, game-physics

I'm rendering three images over a stack of 55 invaders for my space invaders game. Each time I remove an invader, the image on that invader moves and overlaps the image of the invader next to it.

```
  var invaderImage = new Image();
  invaderImage.src = "img/alien1-2.png";
  var invaderImage1 = new Image();
  invaderImage1.src = "img/alien1.png";
  var invaderImage2 = new Image();
  invaderImage2.src = "img/alien2-2.png";

for (var i = 0; i < this.innvaders.length; i++) {
    var invader = this.invaders[i];
    if (i <= 11) {
      ctx.drawImage(
        invaderImage,
        invader.x - invader.width,
        invader.y - invader.height,
        invader.width * 2.0,
        invader.height * 2.0
      );
    }
    if (i > 11 && i <= 32) {
      ctx.drawImage(
        invaderImage1,
        invader.x - invader.width,
        invader.y - invader.height,
        invader.width * 2.0,
        invader.height * 2.0
      );
    }
    if (i > 32 && i<=55) {
      ctx.drawImage(
        invaderImage2,
        invader.x - invader.width,
        invader.y - invader.height,
        invader.width * 2.0,
        invader.height * 2.0
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you utilize the alpha channel within these images?

Comment: @Solvalou No I don't